# Hilbert space-filling curve overlap / ghost nodes

Tags: algorithm, sorting, geolocation, geometry

I have implemented a function which converts me a three dimensional point set to Hilbert space-filling curve coordinates.

If I sort the curve coordinates and split them in (for example in 4) equal sets I will have some nice separate clustered point sets.

Is there a simple way how I can calculate some sort of overlapping?

For example if I separate my point set into two parts is there a simple
way to find the points which are close to the cut? 
So I can generate point sets which overlap each other ?

Answer (score 0):

When its 2 equal sets you can try the moore curve when possible.

[image]